# 1000 дублей страниц. Как решить?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, редирект

Есть сайт на php.
Страница типа **site.com/page.html**

Проблема вот в чем:

Если добавить хоть один символ в конце урла, например **site.com/page.html5** то создается дубль страницы вот так: **site.com/page.html5.html**

Обнаружил что в индексе есть одна и та же страница по сотням адресов типа:
**site.com/page.html.html.html.html.html**
или
**site.com/page.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html**
и до бесконечности.

в htaccess есть вот что

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.+)\.(html|php)$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}.html [R=301,L]
```

без него страницы доступны по другим вариантам, например вот так: **site.com/page.345** или **site.com/page.teghfhjghjkk**, вобщем с любым набором символов и любым их количеством.
но тогда нет вышеперечисленных дублей с html

404 отдает только если в урле страницы есть ошибка, но не после точки.

**site.com/page** - вот так 200

**site.com/pagrd** - вот так 404

Голову сломал уже. Кто может сталкивался с подобным

Comment: ну так и на кой вам rewriteRule если от него одни проблемы?

Comment: В том то и проблема. Я хотел исправить дубли, которые я написал ниже. Они исправились, но появились другие.